# DropDownList after reset button c#

Tags: c#, dropdown

I have a c# dropdownlist inside a form.  My goal is to hit a reset button and set the entire page back to the way it was when I first loaded the page.  My textboxes are clear and everything is where it should be except my dropdownlist.  It displays the last selected dropdownlist Item selected.  I would like it to go back to the initial selection when I reload the page.  How would I do this?

```
     DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
```

or

```
     DropDownList.Clear();
```

Doesn't work

Comment: Setting `SelectedIndex` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex= -1
```